# Is it possible to Hide Column in Editable grid view of D365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I've tried doing it with exporting the solution and changes the XML code and then importing it again.
as you can see in the image two bars after 'Do You Want to' column. But when I open this grid in Unified client interface it is still visible.

> [image: Picture]

like in this grid.if 'isAllowOverride' is True I want to make 'Do you want to' be editable. But 'isAllowOverride' has to be invisible from User end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are editing the xml for such customization. But this can be easily configured in UI itself.

Go to the form editor, open the subgrid properties, check the view it’s configured to show, edit the view columns to remove the unwanted ones, save the view and set the subgrid with the correct edited view again (there’s a product bug which switch to the default Active view), save & publish the form. That’s it.

[image]

**Update**:

We cannot have two different layouts for Display mode vs Edit mode. That being said, you have to [disable the editable grid columns based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694118/7920473).